# python calling an external cmd and redirect stdout to file

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, windows-console

Error message:

```
Failed to open output_file_path/**.txt
```

Code:

```
cmd = 'showTxt "%s" > "%s"' % (file_path, output_file_path)
LoggerInstance.log('[cmd] '+cmd)

#os.system(cmd)
splited_cmd=shlex.split(cmd)

p = subprocess.Popen(splited_cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#p.wait()
output = p.stderr.read()
print output

LoggerInstance.log('[console std error]'+ output)
```

How to redirect stdout to a file in a cmd?

Comment: What is the value of `output_file_path`?

Comment: `Popen(splited_cmd, stdout=open(output_file_path, "w"), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use pipes in the commands you call, you have to create two subprocesses and use the stout of one as stdin for the other. Too complicated! Either you save the stout into the file using python or you put your command into a shell script and call that file with subprocess.

Comment: @AntoinePelisse thanks antoine it works, can u make it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a `file-handler` as `stdout` parameter to `Popen`, i.e:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(splited_cmd,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=open(output_file_path, "w"))
```

Of course, be ready to catch the exception that it can throw.